# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hbm2ddl

hi my tables are as follows:

1- **medical_company**:

- medical_company_id **foreign key** on **account_entity** table **account_entity_id** column (not a pk)
- column1
- column2
- column3

2- **account_entity**:

- **account_entity_id** (pk)
- column1
- column2
- column3

3- **person:**

- **person_id** (pk)
- column1
- column2
- column3

4- **employee_company:**

- company_id foreign key on **medical_company** table on **medical_company_id**
- employee_id foreign key on **person** table on **person_id**
- column1
- column2

**ENTITIES:**

1- **MedicalCompany:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "medical_company")
public class MedicalCompany implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinColumn(name = "medical_company_id", referencedColumnName = "account_entity_id")
private AccountEntity accountEntity;
```

}

2- **AccountEntity:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_entity")
public class AccountEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "account_entity_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Long id;

}
```

3- **Person:**

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "person_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Long id;

}
```

4- **EmployeeCompanyId**:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeCompanyId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne
    private MedicalCompany medicalCompany;

    @Size(max = 150, message = "{long.value}")
    @Column(name = "title_text", length = 150, nullable = true)
    private String titleText;

    @Column(name = "employee_manager")
    private long employeeManager;


}
```

5- **EmployeeCompany:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_company")
@AssociationOverrides(value = {
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.medicalCompany", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "medical_company_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.person", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "person_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.titleText"),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.employeeManager") })
public class EmployeeCompany implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmployeeCompanyId pk = new EmployeeCompanyId();

    @Transient
    public void setEmployeeManager(long employeeManager) {
        this.pk.setEmployeeManager(employeeManager);
    }

    public long getEmployeeManager() {
        return pk.getEmployeeManager();
    }

    @Transient
    public void setTitleText(String titleText) {
        this.pk.setTitleText(titleText);
    }

    public String getTitleText() {
        return pk.getTitleText();
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.pk.setPerson(person);
    }

    @Transient
    public Person getPerson() {
        return this.pk.getPerson();
    }

    public void setMedicalCompany(MedicalCompany medicalCompany) {
        this.pk.setMedicalCompany(medicalCompany);
    }

    @Transient
    public MedicalCompany getMedicalCompany() {
        return this.pk.getMedicalCompany();
    }

    public void setPk(EmployeeCompanyId pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    public EmployeeCompanyId getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

}
```

when trying to run the application, i am getting the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: medical_company_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(medical_company) and its related supertables and secondary tables
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:550)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(AnnotationConfiguration.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
```

please advise why i am getting this error, and how to solve it.

Comment: it was solved? I have same situation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This error is telling you that there is no column on the medical_company table called medical_company_id. The column on medical_company is just called id.

Comment: but there's a foreign key with this name ! `@JoinColumn(name = "medical_company_id" `

Answer (score 44):

I would remove the referencedColumnName attribute in MedicalCompany because you are naming the primary key field of AccountEntity. I think it is only necessary if you if it references a non-primary-key field.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "medical_company_id", referencedColumnName = "account_entity_id")
```

Comment: This is the problem that I was having (on Hibernate 6.0.13.Final)

Comment: Awesome !  Solved my issue as well for Hibernate 5.3.1.  However, I only started seeing this issue as soon as I started using hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers property in my persistence.xml. Not sure why.

Comment: Solved my issue as well!! This should be marked as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I received same error for different situation. I try to join 2 table with String key. This code block send same error.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "SHIPMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_SHIPMENT_GROUP")
private List<ProductShipment> productShipments = new ArrayList<>();
```

I solved question with adding column and Fetch type (I have 2 join in the entity so I need to add FetchMode)=>

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "SHIPMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PRODUCT_SHIPMENT_GROUP")
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<ProductShipment> productShipments = new ArrayList<>();

@Column(name = "PRODUCT_SHIPMENT_GROUP")
private String productShipmentGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your parent entity's primary key name: `@Column(name = "id")` is the same name as the referencedColumnName (foreign key) in the child entity: `@JoinColumn(name = "created_by", referencedColumnName = "id")`

I.e: id = id

Answer (score 0):

This might happen if you removed column from entity but column referenced by another entity

Answer (score -1):

For those who ran into this problem and are using `globally_quoted_identifiers`, this helped me:

Change

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "new_col_1", referencedColumnName = "ref_col_1"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "new_col_2", referencedColumnName = "ref_col_2")
})
```

To

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "new_col_1", referencedColumnName = "`ref_col_1`"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "new_col_2", referencedColumnName = "`ref_col_2`")
})
```

Notice the backtick wrapping the `referencedColumnName` value.