# @JoinColumn gives error "column with logical name ID not found" in Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having below annotation on column in my entity class.

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "INQUIRYID", referencedColumnName="ID", updatable=false, insertable=false)
private MyTable myInquiry;
```

It was giving below error on runtime.

```
column with logical name ID not found in entity class
```

*As the referenced column is a primary key*, I removed the referencedColumnName attribute and updated to below

```
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "INQUIRYID", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private MyTable myInquiry;
```

This works perfectly with **Hibernate 5.3** but as soon as I go to **hibernate 4** , I see  some anomalies.

In hibernate 5 I get this issue only with columns which are referring some ID(PK) of another class. However, in hibernate 4 I see this error for non-pk columns as well.

I start to get the same error for columns which are referring non primary keys.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "AB", referencedColumnName = "AB")
private MyTable someData;
```

Above code gives me error in **hibernate 4**

```
Column with logical name AB not found in entity class.
```

*Here, AB is a non primary key column* .So I can't remove referencedColumnName attribute.

Is it purely because of hibernate version or there is a different reason for such behavior ?

Referred this : [Similar Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624633/org-hibernate-mappingexception-unable-to-find-column-with-logical-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7713) for hibernate 4.1.7

A workaround for this issue is surrounding the column name with gave accents.

> Unable to find column with logical name: id in
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Table(template) and its related supertables and
>   secondary tables
>
> @ManyToOne @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column =
>   @JoinColumn(name = "template", referencedColumnName = "id")),
>   @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "'custom'",
>   referencedColumnName = "type")) }) This is caused by identifying the
>   column names within the logicalToPhysical map of
>   TableColumnNameBinding. Within this map the column names are
>   surrounded by grave accents (`id`) while the check do a lookup to the
>   map with plain column name (id).
>
> A workaround for this issue is surrounding the column name with gave
>   accents.
>
> @ManyToOne @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column =
>   @JoinColumn(name = "template", referencedColumnName = "`id`")),
>   @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "'custom'",
>   referencedColumnName = "`type`")) })